# Get value of dictionary in a list in a dictionary

Tags: python, list, search, dictionary

I want to get a value to a known key in a Dictionary. Simple but this dictionary is in a list of dictionarys and the list is in a dictionary.

example:

```
{u 'd1': 1, 'd2':2 , 'd3': [{'e1':'muh','e2':'mia' ...},{'e1':'wuff', 'e2':'kickeriki'...},...]}
```

and i want to get all values of key `'e2`' in `'d3'`. Is there a super fast way?

EDIT*:
thank you!

results:

```
Blender: 8.82148742676e-06
Oscar:   4.05311584473e-06
```

I will take list comp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, using list comprehensions:

```
d = { 'd1': 1,
      'd2': 2 ,
      'd3': [{'e1':'muh','e2':'mia'}, {'e1':'wuff', 'e2':'kickeriki'}]}

[inner['e2'] for inner in d['d3']]
=> ['mia', 'kickeriki']
```

Answer (score 0):

A short answer based in list comprehensions is:

```
[ d[k] for d in data['d3'] if k in d ]
```

Where `data` is the data structure in your example and `k` the key you are looking for.

This alternative does not assume `k` is present in all subordinate dictionaries.

Tested with

```
data= {'d1': 1, 'd2':2 , 'd3': [{},{'e1':'muh','e2':'mia'},{},{'e1':'wuff', 'e2':'kickeriki'},{}]}
k= 'e1'
```

Result

```
['muh', 'wuff']
```

If clause `if k in d` is eliminated, this results in an exception as `d[k]` is executed for a dictionary that does not contain `k`.

Comment: They were **obvious** (to me :-) )  Thanks for your comment.